# JBeret Queueing Mechanism

Tags: jberet, queueing

I'm receiving a bunch of csv files (e.g. 200) at once which I want to read and process **one after the other** with a JBeret job. How would I configure JBeret to achieve that? Is there some sort of queueing mechanism? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running batch jobs in WildFly (which contains jberet as a subsystem),  submitted job execution requests will be started if there is sufficient processing resources available. Otherwise, requests will be queued for later execution. You can configure the `max-threads` attribute in batch-jberet subsystem to influence the number of concurrent job executions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.